# Jobs Messages access blocked with Firefox 60 Tracker Protection on

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Firefox 60 allows the user to enable Tracker Protection for all windows (previous versions only allowed it for private browsing windows). This however breaks Stack Overflow messaging center as the message list in jobs messages is not shown, sticking with "Loading your messages..." screen.

The console prints the following error message:

> source URI is not allowed in this document:
>   “https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Js/third-party/trackjs/2.10.2/tracker.min.js?v=9b876b27b5d7”.

As a side note, I'm also disappointed that Stack Overflow doesn't honor the "Do not track" browser header, as this tracker should have never been loaded in the first place.

Comment: Just to clarify because the name is confusing: trackjs is used to track *JavaScript errors*, not to track users.

Comment: Its purpose may be to track errors, but does it end up tracking users too? Those error logs look pretty detailed, including [information about what you clicked on and how many characters you typed into form inputs you didn't send](https://docs.trackjs.com/ui/telemetry-timeline#visitor-events).

Comment: If I were writing a tracking protection blacklist, I'd probably blacklist this too.